# Questões colocadas no Stack EN e no PT, tem algum problema?

Tags: suporte

Existe algum problema em colocar questões no aqui, no Stack PT e colocar a mesma momentos depois no Stack EN?

Eu fiz isso, e não sei se é contra alguma regra. Colocar no EN, acredito que abrange uma maior quantidade de pessoas, por enquanto, mas aqui eu terei sempre uma resposta clara no meu idioma.

Tem algum problema procurar ter as vantagens que os dois oferecem?

Nota:
Nem sei quais tags devo colocar num assunto como esse, perdoem-me.

Comment: O consenso parece ser que **não** (i.e. "não tem problema", ou "sim, pode"), e vários usuários já fizeram isso sem repercussões negativas. Não há problema inclusive de linkar de uma pra outra (mostrando que a mesma pergunta existe no outro site), embora isso seja mais interessante quando é SOpt -> SOen do que o contrário (há quem discorde).

Comment: Relacionado: [Onde faço pergunta, SO em Português ou em Inglês?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/735/3117)